# How to gzip @font-face example?

Tags: css, gzip, font-face

Can someone provide an example of how to gzip a webfont kit? The generator provided me with this code...what needs changed around?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DesigersBold';
    src: url('desib__-webfont.eot');
    src: url('desib__-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('desib__-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('desib__-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('desib__-webfont.svg#DesigersBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you using Apache and have access to httpd.conf? If so, is gzip compression already enabled?

You can look for this line:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE
```

Or

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
```

If it's the former, you should be able to add the following MIME types so the directive and parameters look like the one below. The MIME types declared here are for **.EOT**, **.TTF**, and **.SVG**. I pulled them from the **mime.types** file in my Apache conf folder. I believe .WOFF is already compressed so you do not need to have it gzipped.

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf image/svg+xml
```

The latter directive SetOutputFilter gzips all files within the container it is stated in. If this location includes your font files, they should already be gzipped when delivered to the client.

Comment: My server is using Apache but I do not have access to httpd.conf since I'm on shared hosting. Is there an alternative?

Comment: You can use/create an .htaccess file and verify whether or not mod_deflate is enabled on your server.


You can try pasting the following into it and verify via http headers to see if the content is being gzipped.

`AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript`

Comment: @waynethec If the AddOutputFilterByType or SetOutputFilter directives aren't already there in the httpd.conf file, where can it be added? Can we add it anywhere or do we need to be careful about where we put it?

Comment: @waynethec just to be clear, you do mean **.EOT** files, right?

0:-P

Comment: @mroncetwice yes! oh my god, that's been up there for 4 years X_X

Answer (score 0):

Send some **parameters** (bogus), server will treat these responses as **text/plain**, and just compress as of text/plain if **DEFLATE** is set on text/plain.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DesigersBold';
    src: url('desib__-webfont.eot?v=1');
    src: url('desib__-webfont.eot?v=1#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('desib__-webfont.woff?v=1') format('woff'),
         url('desib__-webfont.ttf?v=1') format('truetype'),
         url('desib__-webfont.svg?v=1#DesigersBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

**It just works fine!**