# Setting expire headers and gzipping data via .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf, webfonts, expires-header

I'm trying to set it up so that the browser will cache the webfonts for a long period and also attempting to gzip them for a faster download.

From what I can understand you can do this via your `httpd.conf` file in Apache or via `.htaccess`.

I'm not sure how to tell if gzip is enabled though, I read something about searching your `httpd.conf` file for `DEFLATE`; I did that, but found nothing - so not sure if it's enabled or not!?

Anyway, I have put this code below into the `.htaccess` file, partially because I didn't know where to put it in the httpd.conf file and partially because it's easier to make changes in .htaccess file without bothering my host continually.

Here is the code..

```
# Add correct content-type for fonts
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType font/x-woff .woff
AddType image/svg+xml .svg

# Compress compressible fonts
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf font/otf image/svg+xml

# Add a far future Expires header for fonts
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType font/ttf "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType font/otf "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType font/x-woff "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
```

Now, I'm wondering if this is correct or not as I also seen this similar, but different code for the expiry..

```
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
```

Does it matter where you place it in the `.htaccess` file or can it go anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExpiresByType can go in your httpd.conf, virtualhost config or htaccess, as shown in the apache documentation overview box at the top of each directive entry:

[image: Apache Documentation screenshot]

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html#expiresbytype

The Context listing is how you can tell which configuration files you can put your various Apache directive types into.

Assuming you are using PHP, your phpinfo details should tell you if gzip is enabled.

[image: PHPInfo Screenshot]

**Edit**

In response to your question about correct way MIME type for your fonts, in terms of their file association with the Apache Server, my mime.types file (found in apache conf folder where your httpd.conf lives) tells me that

```
application/x-font-(extension)
```

would be the association to use with ExpiresByType. I would suggest getting the fonts working first, and then checking the headers for the font url to see if its giving proper expiration date.

[image]

As for the browsers receiving the web fonts, [this article](http://www.jbarker.com/blog/2011/web-fonts-mime-types) seems to indicate that MIME types aren't considered and thus don't matter. But yet [this one](http://www.jbarker.com/blog/2011/resource-interpreted-font-transferred-mime-type) seems to contradict that. As I understand it, there is no official font/ MIME type so any browser implementation is outside the MIME specifications.

Related questions:

[Proper MIME type for fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871655/proper-mime-type-for-fonts)

[Correct Apache AddType directives for font MIME types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415640/correct-apache-addtype-directives-for-font-mime-types)

I've not seen anything specifying placement requirements in .htaccess so you should be safe putting these rules wherever you see fit, although if you do AddTypes you need to do so above any further directives that reference that declared Type. It's probably best to put these near the top above your rewrite rules.

Comment: Also the AddOutputFilterByType is allowed in htaccess, so that part should be ok. Here's another SO question covering gzipping fonts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506347/how-to-gzip-font-face-example

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you have any idea about which version is correct with regards to the two different ones I posted when setting expires on the fonts? Also can you put that code anywhere in .htaccess? Like it doesn't matter if it goes above or below mod rewrites for example.

Comment: Great thanks! One thing I do want to clarify though is that I found it kinda weird that my phpinfo page said I did have gzip enabled (or accepted) but nothing about it in my `httpd.conf` file so I asked my host to check on it and they said that `mod_deflate` wasn't installed; which they then went ahead and installed for me. So I guess they're different meanings!?